# Robertson´s weekday function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I need to program a function for the weekday Robertson formula in Haskell.
Currently I receive an error message("Not in scope" when each variables(A, B, C, D, E). However, I do not know what the error is? Is it perhaps "where"?

```
wochentag :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> String
wochentag tag monat jahr = wochentage !! fromInteger (robertson tag monat jahr) where


wochentage :: [String]
wochentage = ["Sonntag","Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag"]



robertson :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer

robertson tag monat jahr = D + tag +77 +E + (B quot 400) - 2 * (B quot 100) mod 77 where

                        A = monat + 10
                        B = ((monat - 14) quot 12) + jahr
                        C = A - 12 * (A quot 13)
                        D = (( 13 * C - 1) quot 5)
                        E = 5 * ( B mod 100) quot 4
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: "I need to" - so this is homework. Pay attention in class, ask your fellow students (perhaps they did), ask your teacher/instructor/lecturer (I'm sure he explained very well what to do).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Values cannot be defined starting with a capital letter.

2) Infix operators should be surrounded with a single quotes like that:

```
robertson :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
robertson tag monat jahr = d + tag + 77 +e + (b `quot` 400) - 2 * (b `quot` 100) `mod` 77 where

                        a = monat + 10
                        b = ((monat - 14) `quot` 12) + jahr
                        c = a - 12 * (a `quot` 13)
                        d = (( 13 * c - 1) `quot` 5)
                        e = 5 * ( b `mod` 100) `quot` 4
```